# Reference Request: introductory text for advanced type of differential equation

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

I am looking for an introductory reference to advanced differential equation, for example $x'(t) = x(t+1)$. The term "advanced" makes the search quite challenging using Google. The topic is sometimes introduced in-passing in other delay or functional textbook. Perhaps something at the level of "A First Course in Integral Equations" by Abdul-Majid Wazwaz is most appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the tag [advanced-differential-equations] because it is not a tag that existed before, and I don't believe it is an established name for a type of differential equation. Indeed, as you note, its not practical to search for anything with this name.

Comment: I looked at the book you mentioned but it didn't help guide me to understand what you are looking for (might be my ignorance of the subject, however). Are you looking for asymptotic and perturbative methods (e.g. [**Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387989315) by Bender/Orszag), qualitative and stability methods from a dynamical systems viewpoint (e.g. [**Ordinary Differential Equations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0262510189) by Arnold, **(continued)**

Comment: or [**Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0123495504) by Hirsch/Smale), classical analysis of existence and uniqueness results (e.g. [**Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0898747554) by A. Coddington/Levinson), etc.? Perhaps you want a general purpose upper-undergraduate/beginning-graduate level "second course" type of text, such as [**Ordinary Differential Equations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471860034) by Birkhoff/Rota?

Comment: By the way, isn't the ODE example you gave trivially separable, followed by extremely simple integrations? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I suspect that the ODE example he gave is supposed to be of [delay type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). Its solvable by inductively integrating assuming that you give initial data on some interval of size one

Comment: @Calvin Khor: I wondered whether $x(t+1)$ was intended to be a product or a function evaluation, and I decided to "play dumb" because if it was function evaluation and the OP simply overlooked the ambiguity, then possibly the OP would more likely watch out for potential ambiguities (of any kind) in the future (due to not having explicitly been told of the ambiguity, but instead having to discover it), which will help with future writing (not just here, but communications with colleagues, research papers, etc.) and teaching (if applicable).

Comment: @Calvin Khor: I didn't notice until just now that one of the tags is "delay-differential equations", a tag that was actually present in the first version of the question (roughly 12 hours *before* I made my first comments). Nonetheless, I think some more context about what is desired is called for.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I agree more context would be great; the same motivation also led me to make the edit to the post which I changed $x'=x(t+1)$ to the current version. Actually, consulting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation#Types_of_functional_differential_equations), it would seem that the above FDE (though equivalent to a delay DE) should be called an "advanced" FDE, or an "advanced differential difference equation", explaining the creation of the tag I removed

Comment: @Calvin Khor: Until now, I didn't realize "advanced" was a term used to refer to a **type** of differential equation. I was thinking the OP wanted an advanced level book (i.e. not an elementary ODE book; not a book for a first course in ODEs). It seems that the caution I used when deciding to write "(might be my ignorance of the subject, however)" in my first comment is justified!